# Bootcamp and disk space

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, spaces

I tried to install Windows via Bootcamp and when I first launched BC it said (something like): The drive cannot be partitioned because there is not enough free space and it said I needed 40gb.

However, when I tried to check my total storage in the "about" section it said that I had over 100gb free space! Then when I double checked with Disk Utility it said that I had 33GB free space! in Disk Utility it also said:

Available: 103,21 GB (69,25 GB   Purgeable)

What does this mean?

I have deleted a ton of files but the free disk space is just shrinking! Not getting bigger!

Mac OS version: 10.13.4
I do not Use Time Capsule

Comment: Do you use Time Machine for backups to your Mac via external hard drives?

Comment: No I don't, I have actually never used time machine

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to look into it, but it's actually solved right now! Thanks to Steve Chambers!

Comment: This question here may be similar. Run one of the recommended programs mentioned to see what is using up the space on the hard drive. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/16364/258380

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You leave out some necessary information for us to help you. We are going to need (at least) the version of macOS on your Mac. it's under the Apple Menu, "About This Mac..."

Assuming that you have the latest (High Sierra, 10.13.4) it is possible that the problem is that of Time Machine snapshots (again assuming that you use Time Machine). Something that Apple introduced in High Sierra and something we are all learning how to work with even now.

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311491/cannot-partition-internal-drive-to-install-bootcamp-because-of-apfs-high-sierra/312831#312831) shows how to list and then delete snapshots. Once you do that see if you can then resize the macOS partition to a size sufficient for Boot Camp installation.

Failing that please edit your question and add in macOS version, which Mac you have, if you use Time machine, etc.

Comment: Alright, I've updated the post now. Also I followed the steps in the article and now when I check disk utility everything says the same except for "other volumes" which now says −110,6 GB

Comment: hmm, suddenly it just flipped! I now have 110gb free storage. I assume that you provided the correct solution! Thank You!